# Picasso not loading image, and no error logged

Tags: android, picasso

My usecase is to load images from a URL, and I am using picasso, in the following way to acheive that.

```
    ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tasklayout);
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    Picasso.with(this).load(taskFieldDao.data).into(imageView);
    ll.addView(imageView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(800, 800));
```

What I see is a 800 * 800 whitespace with no image in it. Looking at the logs, there doesn't seem to any problem. Atleast picasso doesn't record anything.

Comment: try to open your image url in a browser

Comment: Yes it works. Its the same url used in ios and android. iOS is able to get image from the url

Comment: I am also facing same issue right now with Glide too. It's not loading image from sign in reponse

Comment: Are you sure your ImageView is actually visible and properly laid out? Maybe put a simple image resource in it instead to see if it's Picasso or your layout that's at fault?

Comment: Try putting a drawable in error ().  See if that loads or not. If that loads error you can attach an error listener and find out what's going on.

Comment: also try loading image with a placeholder

Comment: That's chaining error () to your Picasso.with () chain.

Answer (score 0):

I replicate your problem with button click and it is working. You can as well check the your path is correct

```
 downloadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.download_button);

    downloadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {                

            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(PicassoDownloadActivity.this);
            Picasso.with(PicassoDownloadActivity.this).load(Helper.imageDownloadPath).into(imageView);
            relativeLayout.addView(imageView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(800, 800));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Picasso won't typically give errors when something goes wrong, i suggest doing something like this:

```
ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tasklayout);
final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
Picasso.with(this).load(taskFieldDao.data).into(imageView, new Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        ll.addView(imageView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(800, 800));
   }

    @Override
    public void onError() {
        Log.e("Picasso","Image load failed);
    }
});
```